# how to update Core data from server

Tags: ios, core-data

I am new to IOS app development. I have an application in which i use core data. I upload the data in data model through comma separated txt file. This code is written in appdelegate.m. The app shows the jpeg files stored on server. It picks up the image name from the data model in core data. When the user will download my app from app store the default data will be downloaded to user mobile. The images will keep changing in my app every week. Hence the data model has to be updated every week. My question is : How can core data be put on some server (as far my understanding its local with app) so that my app connects to server rather than local core data for user app? I have always worked with SQL Server for my web apps. Core data is little confusing for me. Can we have core data as a server somewhere may be on cloud?

Comment: CoreData is only for iOS.

Comment: Have you looked at CloudKit? And Core Data is for *client side* on iOS and Mac OS X, to be precise.

Comment: If core data is for client side then what to use for server in mobile app ? Can iOS apps connect to sql server or other RDBMS ? How do mobile apps like trip case update their data which changes so often ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, Core Data is your object hierarchy for your client side code.  If you want to store data on a server then you need to look into CloudKit or some other server service.

As for Core Data being confusing, I would **strongly** suggest reading the updated documentation on Core Data that is available as part of the current beta for iOS and OS X or read my book :)

Nevertheless, Core Data is client side only.  You can sync between Core Data and server services but that is outside of the scope of your question.